# Is it possible to have .iso with live distribution of linux but without an installer?

Tags: filesystems, iso

I thought **ISO** file is a file that allows us to **install** some distribution and some part of it (not sure what is it) gives us possibility to run **live version** (without installing the OS). However our professor claimed there can be only **live** version on **ISO**, without possibility of installing it.

My questions are:

1. Is professor right?
2. What allows us to run live version? Is it property of OS? Property of way **ISO** file is created? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Is professor right?

Your professor is wrong. And: You are wrong. Good news: nobody cares about who's wrong :)

An iso file is just an image of a physical medium (originally, a CD-ROM). Whether or not it contains a live system, or just an automatic installer running on a different OS, has nothing to do with it.

Both exist.

> What allows us to run live version? Is it property of OS? Property of way iso file is created? Something else?

"Running" software is a property of your computer hardware, otherwise it would not be a computer. To know what to run, the firmware (i.e., the software that is "baked into" your computer) adheres to a couple of standardized methods of looking for devices from which to load software (e.g., a live system).

So, it's

1. Your computer's hardware ability to run software
2. your computer's hardware interfaces giving a standardized interface to some storage medium (IDE CD-ROM, SCSI DVD, USB thumb drive, SATA hard drive, NVMe, …)
3. A standard on how to store software on these media so that the computer can find it
4. Your computer's firmware following the standard
5. The software being put on the medium as specified by the standard
6. The software being compatible with your computer's hardware

So, no, it's not a property of "OS"; a bootable medium does not necessarily contain an OS.

Comment: Thank you a lot for an answer! Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but I need few clarification. I downloaded two different iso files of kali linux. When I run them in VirtualBox, the grub-like menu appeared. In one case there was an option "live boot" in second one there weren't. If it would be related only to hypervisor, shouldn't this menu be the same?

Comment: no, it shouldn't. GRUB is already software running from your medium, it can do whatever it wants after being loaded in a particular way.

Comment: But even if there is no such option in this GRUB software, I can force it somehow, am I right? I mean, I can say to my hardware (firmware?) both, "run this OS wtihout installing" and "install this OS". If so, how can I search for a way of doing that?

Comment: No. Your hardware knows nothing about the software it runs. "Installation" is not a term from the hardware world. That's only a usage concept. There's no special "installation" switch in your hardware. Your hardware just executes software. Whether that software is a virus, an operating system booted to let you use it as what you think of as a "live system", or an operating system booted to copy files to another storage medium, which is what you mean when you say "installation": The hardware doesn't see that.

Comment: One caveat; a "live CD" where you can run the full OS (eg Linux) without installing on a disk requires the OS to be setup in such a way that file it would normally write (resolv.conf? messages? ntp.conf? $HOME? /tmp?) are sent to a tmpfs ramdisk.  Because, obviously, the ISO is considered read-only.    Dedicated installers are written from scratch assuming this, but a full Linux OS used on a live image won't be.